# window.print() , google maps blank space between screenshot

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, google-maps

I'm currently working on an aspx Page , the main page functionality is to display a google maps path composed by several markers (huge amount) , i'd need to add a print option (A3/A4 Format) ,and i've been using the window.print() function to achieve this , as i've been stuck having issues trying with other methods (like google maps api) , here's my current issue : using window.print() i'm able to get the printing of the map with the right formats , however there's a blank space being showed on the printout , here's an example A4(1050,625):
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exfXE.jpg)

The code:

```
function print(width,height){

            var cDiv = document.createElement('div');
            cDiv.setAttribute('id','mainContainer');
            cDiv.innerHTML='<div id="mapContainer"></div>';

            var jqMapContainer = $("#map");

            mapContainer = jqMapContainer[0];

            var origDisplay = [],
            origMapParent = mapContainer.parentNode;
            body = window.document.body;
            childNodes = body.childNodes;

            // hide all body content
            $.each(childNodes, function (i, node) {
                if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                    origDisplay[i] = node.style.display;
                    node.style.display = 'none';
                }
            });

            body.appendChild(cDiv);

            var rc = document.getElementById('mapContainer');

            rc.appendChild(mapContainer);

            $("#mainContainer").width(width);
            $("#mainContainer").height(height);
            $(mapContainer).width(width);
            $(mapContainer).height(height);

            setTimeout(function () {
                window.print();
            }, 4000);

            var _self = this;
            // allow the browser to prepare before reverting
            setTimeout(function () {

                // put the chart back in
                origMapParent.appendChild(mapContainer);

                $("#mainContainer").remove();

                // restore all body content
                $.each(childNodes, function (i, node) {
                    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                        node.style.display = origDisplay[i];
                    }
                });

                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

            }, 4000);
        }
```

the div element that contains the map:

```
<div class="CenterRightColMap">
            <div class="contentCC">
                <div id="map" class="mapFullPage"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Style:

```
div.mapFullPage
{
    width:100%; 
    height:98%; 
}
div.contentCC {
    position:relative;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    /*background: #FFFFFF;
    color: #666666;
    font-family: Tahoma,Verdana,Helvetica,Helvetica-Narrow,sans-serif;*/
    text-align:center;
    height:100%
}
div.CenterRightColMap 
{
    position:absolute;
    float: auto;
    left:430px;
    right:20px;
    height:85%;
    min-height:85%;
    FONT-SIZE: 8pt;
    background-color: #CECECE;
    FONT-FAMILY: Verdana;
    padding: 5px
}
```

Comment: Is it always the same portion that is missing, or does it vary? Looks to me as if this was simply a problem with the map loading all the tiles in time - and like you tried to fix that with an arbitrary 4 second timeout somehow?

Comment: I've noticed that the missing space varies according to  $mapContainer width  & height , also regarding the timeout i've noticed no difference setting up 1 or 10 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution here : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426294
Managed to fix it using adding the following style to the page

```
<style>.gm-style div > img {position: absolute;}</style>
```

Appears to be a bug from gm